# MVC WAB API object as HttpResponseMessage's HttpContent

Tags: xml, json, model-view-controller, httpwebrequest

I have an MVC WEB API service and i want to send every response as an HttpResponseMessage.
This case i have a class looking like this:

```
public class Quota
{
    public int docs_quota { get; set; }
    public int pages_quota { get; set; }
    public int size_quota { get; set; }
}
```

in the response's content i want to send a Quota object, but i don't want to serialize it by myself, i want to let the service do it, so i don't have to bother if it's serialized as json or xml.

How can i do that?

Sincerely,

Zoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i found it out, it's pretty easy:

```
Quota q = GetQuota();
var response = new HttpResponseMessage<Quota>(q);
    return response;
```

It will return with a statuscode 200(okay) and the q will be serialized in json/xml in the content.